# Can this circuit be a Schmitt trigger?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm just learning about Schmitt triggers with op amps. I have the circuit below, and I tried to go through the calculations to find the high and low thresholds. What I'm understanding from my calculations is that the high voltage threshold and low voltage threshold are the same (-5V). Is this correct, or did I make a mistake?

[image: circuit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short:

- Yes, it's a Schmitt trigger.
- Yes, you have made a mistake.
- Output low / high happens at Vin =~ -10V*
- Output high / low happens at Vin =~ -15V*.

*I have slightly adjusted Vout range to make sums easier. Result is essentially the same. As shown the zener is being used in an unapproved manner.

---

Longer:  Loosely a Schmit trigger can be considered to be a comparator with hysteresis or positive feedback such that the switching decision point alters when the circuit ir triggered to provide a "deadband". On that basis this IS a Schmitt trigger circuit.

**Using a zener to clamp Vout as shown is a VERY bad idea.**
The opamp is using all its output to try to drive the zener high. This is a non-approved way to do what is desired BUT OK for working through the example

Without using your notes.
 Vout swings from about -0.8V to about 4.3V. For practical purposes we can work with 0V and 5V and get an OK answer to the main question.

Vref on the inverting input (OA-)is -5V. This does not change.

Vout is low = 0V when the non inverting input OA+ is below -5V and high = +5V when the non inverting input is above -5V.

When Vout = 0V then the trigger condition occurs when Vin = -10V, so OA+ = -5V.

When OA+ rises above -10V Vout rises to +5V.
 So immediately OA+ rises to -2.5V (half way between Vin at -10V and Vout at +5V.
So the opamp is now ell away from the switching point.

To switch back OA+ needs to fall to -5V and to achieve this Vin will need to fall to -15V (as OA- is now +5 - (5 - - 15V) = 5 - 10 = -5V.)

SO the switching boundaries are
 -10V rising = output low to high and
 -15V falling = output = high to low.

Comment: Ok great! But what was my mistake again? Thanks for the feedback about clamping the output voltage!

Comment: @ChrisHarris - I don't know what your mistake was as I did not go through your derivation. I could do so **BUT** it would be far more useful for you (and easier for me :-) ) for you to take my answer and apply it to your calculations and see where they diverge. The answer is intuitive - if its not adjust your thinking until it is :-). Clearly OA- is always fixed. Clearly OA+ is pulled even higher when Vout switches high and even lower when Vout switches low so  the opamp MUST chase its tail to be able top switch. Start from there and it should work.